# Tableau IF THEN statement

Tags: tableau-api

Please see my code below. I am relatively new to Tableau. I have figured out a lot of the basics, however, I believe my coding is rather inefficient and causing extended periods of calculation. I am hoping someone might be able to help me figure out a more efficient way to code the following:

Depending upon the product, tier, and % Attainment, a different value is derived. As one can see - Product B, Tier 40-60 should calculate 40 when % attainment reaches 0.5 (50%).... so on and so forth. The IF statement goes all the way up to 100%.

```
IF [Product] = "PRODUCTB"
THEN
    IF [TIER] = "40-60"
        THEN
            IF [% Attainment] = 0.5 THEN 40
            ELSEIF [% Attainment] = 0.51 THEN 80
            ELSEIF [% Attainment] = 0.52 THEN 120
            ELSEIF [% Attainment] = 0.53 THEN 160
            ELSEIF [% Attainment] = 0.54 THEN 200
```

Comment: generally speaking, if you have `if(cond1) { if (cond2) { ...} }`, then you can probably rewrite as `if (cond1 && cond2) { ... }`. and for the attainment stuff, since that's all linear growth, `then 40 + ((%attainment - 0.5) * 100 * 40)` could replace all of those extra checks.

Comment: Thanks. That was 1 of the immediate changes I made.

Comment: Is comparative logic very time consuming for Tableau?

Comment: no idea, but at some point, a bit of math may be more efficient than a repeated set of tests. where that cutover is, not a clue.

Comment: @MarcB you should make that an answer. Great to point out using the linear relationship.

Comment: @specmer Comparative logic is usually not very time consuming but it will depend on how much logic you have in your calculated field as well as how many rows of data you are using. Table or window calculations will naturally take longer than a single-row calculation. Using a data extract will provide a huge performance increase, even with calculated fields because you don't run the calculations each time you view a viz.